# Display inline content on separate lines

Tags: html, css

I have a simple block with content:

```
<div>
    <img src="/img/sample.png" alt="Sample image">
    <span class="colored-text">Company name</span>
    <em>Address</em>
</div>
```

I want 'Company name' and 'Address' to be on separate lines.

And now I have several options available:

Make additional `<div>`s, add a `<br/>` tag between the `<span>` and `<em>` tags and maybe some other solutions.
What is the proper way to add such functionality?

Comment: Then use BLOCK elements, i.e. a DIV instead of a SPAN.

Comment: Any of these will work.  <br /> is the easiest way  <div> tags instead of span and em give you the greatest flexibility if you wanted to change the layout.

Comment: <p>why not a paragraph</p>???

Comment: Because it isn't a paragraph. Software which tries to deduce the meaning of a page's content based on its HTML tags may misinterpret this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should do what semantically makes the most sense. In general, `div` tags are meant to represent some kind of DIVision in the page. If you are simply listing an address it doesn't make sense to do this. I would personally use a `<br />` at the end of the line which adds a line break without making any kind of semantic statement about your content.

Answer (score 4):

You can use only CSS and make the `em` tag break in its own line:

```
div em {display:block}
```

or

```
div em {float:left;clear:both}
```

Either way the Address will break line and you don't have to touch your `HTML`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of options.

```
<div>
    <img src="/img/sample.png" alt="Sample image">
    <span class="colored-text">Company name</span>
    <br />
    <em>Address</em>
</div>
```

or

```
<div>
    <img src="/img/sample.png" alt="Sample image">
    <p class="colored-text">Company name</p>
    <p><em>Address</em></p>
</div>
```

or

```
<ul>
        <li><img src="/img/sample.png" alt="Sample image">
        <span class="colored-text">Company name</span></li>
        <li><em>Address</em></li>
    </ul>
```

and many more, including variations on the listed.

Answer (score 0):

Following CSS will do the trick:

```
span.colored-text{ display:block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a break at the end of each line.

Answer (score 0):

**Possiblity 1 (without CSS):** http://jsfiddle.net/mnnLG/1/

Using `<br />` to skip to a new line.

**Possiblity 2 (with CSS):** http://jsfiddle.net/mnnLG/2/

Using `display:block` CSS to make the inline elements take block attributes.

**Alternate Possibility:**

Wrap each element with a block-type element. It can be `ul/ol`->`li` combination, or a simple `div` element.