# @media for Javascript text animation 2

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, media-queries

I have a Javascript text animation on my homepage and would like to insert an @media command using internal CSS to the homepage scripted text 'we do content'.  I am trying to make this so when viewed on an iphone screen size the text changes to be displayed on three separate lines, rather than one.  ie:

We

Do

Content

I'm at a bit of a loss what to values/ elements to call out for the @media command.  I think maybe  /br may be one of the three things needed but otherwise a bit stumped! It's worth noting this is a wordpress theme and "bk_big_text" is a theme specific text id. Any help greatly appreciated!

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) { 
     .changer (not sure if this is right?) {    
            what goes here?: /br !important;
     }
}
</style>
</head>


<p style="text-align: left;">[bk_big_text size="120" ]

<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
var words = ["content","brand", "identity", "digital", "fresh","integrated", "interactive", "creative", "powerful","witty", "editorial"]; 
var i = 0; 
var text = "We do content"; 
function _getChangedText() {     
    i = (i + 1) % words.length;     
    console.log(words[i]);     
    console.log(i);     
    return text.replace(/content/, words[i]); 
} 
function _changeText() {     
    var txt = _getChangedText();     
    console.log(txt);     
    document.getElementById("changer").innerHTML = txt; 
} 
setInterval("_changeText()", 2200);
// ]]></script>

<span id="changer" style="color: #ffffff;">We do content</span>[/bk_big_text]
```

Comment: Here they list a bunch of possibilities: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14732562/display-inline-content-on-separate-lines>

Comment: That's useful for br/ versus span versus div, but perhaps my question is more simple than this.  On line 4 I have put .changer to reference the script but I think this is wrong?  Then line 5 I don't know what element to put before the br/ - it's not a font-size etc.